# Update Linq2Sql DataContext after StoredProc is executed

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am executing a stored Procedure using Linq2SQL to update a user:

```
var oldUser = _context.Users.Single(u => u.id == id).Clone(); // clone old object
_context.UpdateUserSP("NewName"); //update user via sp
var updatedUser = _context.Users.Single(u => u.id == id); // this is not updated after sp is executed
```

The problem i have her is that the "updatedUser" does not reflect changes done by SP.

I kinda understand why, but i have no idea how to refresh the DataContext to reflect those changes.

I have tried `_context.Refresh(.......);` but i am simply not able to refresh the context.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom method to clear the context's cache.

**Please note that the below code will clear your context's cache completeley**

```
public static void ClearCache(this OneFmDataContext context)
    {
        context.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "ClearCache",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, context, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this as well. Your Datacontext has stale data cause it does not know what your SP has done.

If you create a new DataContext and do the

```
var updatedUser = NEWcontext.Users.Single(u => u.id == id);
```

it will reflect the changes.

Comment: This was/is currently my current solution, I am trying to get rid of making use of more than one datacontext. I'll leave this Question open for another week, and mark as answer if no-one comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `_context.SubmitChanges();` before you retrieve the user.

Comment: nope, this had no effect on context, the "updatedUser" has not changed

Comment: I would assume SubmitChanges() would solve your woes, but obviously not. Can you post the SPROC code as well? And are we assuming there's only one entry in the Users table?